# knockout observable array dynamically added elements value is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, view

I have a view that replicates controls on button click.  I am achieving this through KO's observableArray. The problem I am facing right now is that it does replicate all the controls, but when I try to get that observable array on save it does not have all the elements.I am trying to update the values of hiddenfor elements on text change for phnumber. It works perfectly fine for the first one but when I click add new phone number and enter values, it is all empty except for dropdown value and notes. Check below
[{"IsDomestic":"True","CountryCode":"1","AreaCode":"201","PhoneNumber":"5555555","InternationalNumber":"","Extension":"55","Notes":"test","PrimaryNumberYN":"False","OkToId":"NULL","OkToLeaveMessageYN":"False","phoneTypeDscId":74},{"Notes":"teststestststt","phoneTypeDscId":73}]

**Following is my code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
 //   var temp = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
 //   console.log(temp);
    function PhoneTypeViewModel() {
        this.PhoneType = ko.observable();
        this.selectedPhoneType = ko.observable();
        var newPhone = function () {
            return {
                PhoneID: ko.observable(),
                IsDomestic: ko.observable(),
                CountryCode: ko.observable(),
                AreaCode: ko.observable(),
                PhoneNumber: ko.observable(),
                InternationalNumber: ko.observable(),
                Extension: ko.observable(),
                Notes: ko.observable(),
                PrimaryNumberYN: ko.observable(),
                OkToId: ko.observable(),
                OkToLeaveMessageYN: ko.observable(),
                phoneTypeDscId: ko.observable()
            }
        };
        this.multiplePhone = ko.observableArray([newPhone()]);
        //this.multiplePhone = ko.ko.observable(),([{
        //    PhoneID: 1,
        //    IsDomestic: "",
        //    CountryCode: "",
        //    AreaCode: "",
        //    PhoneNumber: "",
        //    InternationalNumber: "",
        //    Extension: "",
        //    Notes: "",
        //    PrimaryNumberYN: "False",
        //    OkToId: "False",
        //    OkToLeaveMessageYN: "False",
        //    phoneTypeDscId: ""
        //    //  visible : false
        //}]);
        this.addPhone = function () {
            i = i + 1;
            // this.multiplPhone.push(newPhone());
            this.multiplePhone.push({
                PhoneID: ko.observable(),
                IsDomestic: ko.observable(),
                CountryCode: ko.observable(),
                AreaCode: ko.observable(),
                PhoneNumber: ko.observable(),
                InternationalNumber: ko.observable(),
                Extension: ko.observable(),
                Notes: ko.observable(),
                PrimaryNumberYN: ko.observable(),
                OkToId: ko.observable(),
                OkToLeaveMessageYN: ko.observable(),
                phoneTypeDscId: ko.observable()
            });
            //this.multiplePhone.push(
            //   {
            //       //id: i, visible: true
            //       PhoneID: i,
            //       IsDomestic: "",
            //       CountryCode: "",
            //       AreaCode: "",
            //       PhoneNumber: "",
            //       InternationalNumber: "",
            //       Extension: "",
            //       Notes: "",
            //       PrimaryNumberYN: "False",
            //       OkToId: "False",
            //       OkToLeaveMessageYN: "False",
            //       phoneTypeDscId: ""
            //       //  visible : true
            //   }
            //    );
            // console.log(this.multiplePhone()[0]['PhoneID']);
        };
        this.removePhone = function (data) {
            this.multiplePhone.remove(data);
        };
        this.intlTelInpt = function () {
            console.log("test");
            this.intlTelInput({
                autoFormat: true,
                allowExtensions: true,
                utilsScript: "../../Scripts/IntlTelInput/utils.js"
            });
        };
        this.save = function () {
            console.log(ko.toJSON(this.multiplePhone));
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("addPhone", "Patients")',
                type: "POST",
                data: ko.toJSON(this.multiplePhone),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert("Phone successfully added.");
                    $('#phNumber').val("").change();
                    $('#phTypeSelect').val("").change();
                    $('#notes').val("").change();

                    //this.multiplePhone.removeAll();
                   // ko.applyBindings(new PhoneTypeViewModel());
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert("An error has occurred.");
                }
            });
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).load(function () {
            //$(document).on(".intltelinput", function () {
            //    $(this).intlTelInput({
            //        autoFormat: true,
            //        allowExtensions: true,
            //        utilsScript: "../../Scripts/IntlTelInput/utils.js"
            //    });
            //});

            //ko.applyBindings(new multiplePhonesViewModel(), document.getElementById("phoneInfo"));
            //$(document).on('click', ".remove", function () {
            //    console.log("Entered remove function");
            //    i = i - 1;
            //    $(this).closest("div.dynamicTel").remove();

            //});

            $(document).on('focus', "input.phNumber", function () {
                $(this).intlTelInput({
                    autoFormat: true,
                    allowExtensions: true,
                    utilsScript: "../../Scripts/IntlTelInput/utils.js"
                });
            });



            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("getDescriptorListByType", "Descriptor")',
                data: {type : "Phone"},
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    var phoneTypeViewModel = new PhoneTypeViewModel();
                    phoneTypeViewModel.PhoneType(data);
                    ko.applyBindings(phoneTypeViewModel);

                }
            });

            @*$.ajax({`enter code here`
                url: '@Url.Action("getPhoneById", "Phone")',
                data: {Id : -1},
                type: "POST",
                success: function (phone) {
                    var phoneTypeVM = new PhoneTypeViewModel();
                    phoneTypeVM.multiplePhone(phone);
                   console.log(phoneTypeVM);
                }
            });*@
            // $(function () {

            //     $("#phNumber").intlTelInput({
            //         autoFormat: true,
            //         allowExtensions: true,
            //         utilsScript: "../../Scripts/IntlTelInput/utils.js"
            //     });

            //});
            $(document).on('change', "input.phNumber", function () {
                //$('#phNumber').change(function () {
                if ($(this).intlTelInput("isValidNumber") == false) {
                    var err = $('#phNumber').intlTelInput("getValidationError");
                    console.log($('#phNumber').intlTelInput("getValidationError"));
                    console.log(intlTelInputUtils.validationError);
                    switch (err) {
                        case intlTelInputUtils.validationError.INVALID_COUNTRY_CODE:
                            alert("The country code is not valid");
                            $("#error-msg").val("The country code is not valid");

                            break;

                        case intlTelInputUtils.validationError.TOO_SHORT:
                            alert("The phone number is too short");
                            $("#error-msg").val("The phone number is too short");

                            break;

                        case intlTelInputUtils.validationError.TOO_LONG:
                            alert("The phone number is too long");
                            $("#error-msg").val("The phone number is too long");

                            break;

                        case intlTelInputUtils.validationError.NOT_A_NUMBER:
                            alert("The value is not a number");
                            $("#error-msg").val("The value is not a number");

                            break;

                        default:
                            alert("The phone number is not valid");
                            $("#error-msg").val("The phone number is not valid");

                            break;
                    }
                    $("#error-msg").removeClass("hide");
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#primaryNumber').val("False").change();
                    $('#okToID').val("NULL").change();
                    $('#okToLeaveMessage').val("False").change();
                    $('#extension').val("").change();
                    $('#isDomestic').val("True").change();
                    $('#areaCode').val("").change();
                    $('#number').val("").change();
                    $('#intlNumber').val("").change();

                    var countryCode = $('#phNumber').intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode;
                    $('#countryCode').val(countryCode).change();
                    $('#extension').val($('#phNumber').intlTelInput("getExtension")).change();


                    if (countryCode == "1")
                    {
                        $('#number').val(($('#phNumber').intlTelInput("getNumber", intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.NATIONAL).substring(6, 14)).replace('-','')).change();
                        $('#areaCode').val(($('#phNumber').intlTelInput("getNumber", intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.NATIONAL)).substring(1, 4)).change();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#intlNumber').val($('#phNumber').intlTelInput("getNumber")).change();
                        $('#isDomestic').val("False").change();

                    }
                    console.log("country code = " + countryCode);
                    console.log("extension = " + $('#extension').val());
                    console.log("is domestic = " +  $('#isDomestic').val());
                    console.log("number = " + $('#number').val());
                    console.log("area code = " + $('#areaCode').val());
                    console.log("international number" + $('#intlNumber').val());

                }
            });

        });
    });

</script>

@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div i class="row" data-bind="foreach: multiplePhone">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Phone Number ")
                @Html.TextBox("phNumber", "", new { @id = "phNumber", type = "tel", @class = "form-control input-sm phNumber" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PhoneNumber,new { @id = "number", @data_bind = "value:  PhoneNumber" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsDomestic, new { @id = "isDomestic" , @data_bind = "value: IsDomestic" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountryCode, new { @id = "countryCode", @data_bind = "value: CountryCode" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AreaCode, new { @id = "areaCode", @data_bind = "value:  AreaCode" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InternationalNumber, new { @id = "intlNumber", @data_bind = "value: InternationalNumber" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Extension, new { @id = "extension", @data_bind = "value: Extension" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PrimaryNumberYN, new { @id = "primaryNumber", @data_bind = "value: PrimaryNumberYN" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OkToId, new { @id = "okToID", @data_bind = "value: OkToId" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OkToLeaveMessageYN, new { @id = "okToLeaveMessage", @data_bind = "value: OkToLeaveMessageYN" })
                @*<input type="tel" class="form-control input-sm phNumber">*@
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Phone Type ")
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.phoneTypeDscId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control", id = "phTypeSelect", @data_bind = "options: $parent.PhoneType, optionsValue:'DescriptorId', optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: '-- Choose Phone Type --', value: phoneTypeDscId" })
                @*<select class="dropdown" data-bind="options: $parent.PhoneType, optionsValue:'DescriptorId', optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: '-- Choose Phone Type --'"></select>*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phoneTypeDscId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Notes ")
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new {id="notes", @class = "form-control input-sm", @data_bind = "value: Notes" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <br />
                <button data-bind="click: $parent.removePhone.bind($parent), clickBubble: false, visible: $index() > 0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                @*<label data-bind="visible: visible">Remove</label>*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button data-bind="click: addPhone, clickBubble: false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
            <label>Add New Phone Number</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@*<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-default save">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>*@

@*<div class="row">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InternationalNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "internationalPhoneNumber"} })
    </div>*@
<div>
       <div class="col-md-3">

           <input type="submit" value="Add Phone" data-bind="click: save"  class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the element id's which were same every time I clicked add new phone number button. I had to make sure that I had assigned a unique id for each. I just appended the array index to the each element's id and it gives me all the data. 
attr: {id: 'areaCode'+$index() }